# kafka should the consumer and producer have knowledge of the partitions

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to wrap my head around kafka and the thing that confuses me are the partitions.  From all/most of the examples I have seen the consumers/products seem to have implicit knowledge of the partitions, (which partition to write messages to, which partition to read messages from).  Is this correct, I initially thought that partitions are internal to the system and the consumers/producers dont need to know partition information.  If they need to know partition information then aren't we exposing the inner structure of the topic to a certain extent to the outside world?

Answer (score 0):

In kafka every partition in a topic has a set of brokers, and at most one broker leader per partition. You cannot have more consumers of a topic than the number of partitions because otherwise some consumer would be inactive.You can have multiple partitions for a single consumer, but cannot have multiple consumers for a single partition. So the number of partitions must be chosen according to the throughput you expect. The number of partitions can be increased on a topic, but never decreased. When consumers connect to a partition they actually connect to the broker leader to consume messages.
Anyway the partition leader could change, so the consumer would get an error and should send the request for meta-data to the cluster controller in order to get the info on the new partition leader. At consumer startup partitions are assigned according to the kafka parameter partition.assignment.strategy. Of course if consumers start at different times on the same consumer group there will be partition rebalance.

Finally you need a lot of info on the kafka cluser structure as a client.